# Gradle does not copy xml file that store with java file to war file when it assemble

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have the xml file in the following :

```
 src/main/java/com/kh/spider/user.xml
```

when i export war file on `eclipse ide`  it will include this file in the classes in the war file. However, if I let gradle build this project and create war file it won't include this xml file with classes.

Note: I know that I can fix this by moving the xml file into resource folder, but I was not allow to change the directory structure.  So I want to figure out the way to copy this xml file to war file when build in gradle using built.gradle. Can anyone help me with this??

Answer (score 1):

You will have to tell gradle to look in src/main/java for resource files instead of the usual src/main/resources:

```
sourceSets.main.resources {
    srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
    include '**/*.xml'
}
```