# MyBatis not recognizing mapper xml file - Invalid bound statement (not found)

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, mybatis

I am getting this type of error when I tried to extract data from the database.
Somehow MyBatis is not recognizing my mapper xml file, which the interface mapper and xml mapper have the same file name and same directory.
However, when I use this annotation it works `@Select("SELECT id, client_number, name, email, health_condition FROM client.data WHERE id = #{id}")`
I don't want to use @Select annotation but want to use my mapper xml file instead.
Does anyone have any idea to solve this problem??
I'm using Gradle(latest), Java15, and SpringBoot2.4.1

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
> status=500). Invalid bound statement (not found):
> nutri.api.infrastructure.datasource.client.ClientMapper.getClientById
> org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement
> (not found):
> nutri.api.infrastructure.datasource.client.ClientMapper.getClientById
> at
> org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod$SqlCommand.(MapperMethod.java:235)
> at
> org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.(MapperMethod.java:53)
> at
> org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.lambda$cachedInvoker$0(MapperProxy.java:115)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
> at
> org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.cachedInvoker(MapperProxy.java:102)
> at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:85)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58.getClientById(Unknown Source)     at
> nutri.api.infrastructure.datasource.client.ClientDatasource.getClientById(ClientDatasource.java:18)
> at
> nutri.api.infrastructure.datasource.client.ClientDatasource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fcc24d17.invoke()
> at
> org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
> at
> org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
> at
> nutri.api.infrastructure.datasource.client.ClientDatasource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$42a63ac2.getClientById()
> at
> nutri.api.application.service.ClientService.getClientById(ClientService.java:15)
> at
> nutri.api.presentation.controller.ClientApiController.get(ClientApiController.java:20)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
> at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

Comment: It is hard to help with that little information that you provided. Please include mapper xml file and mapper interface.

Comment: @Leo The most common mistake for this error is that the XML is in `src/main/java` instead of `src/main/resources`. As there are many other possible causes for this error, the quickest way to get the answer is to share your project on GitHub. :)

Comment: @ave Here is my project https://github.com/nnakamura95/nutri/tree/develop

Comment: @Leo There seems to be no XML file in the repo.  It should be located in this path : `nutri/nutri-api/src/main/resources/nutri/api/infrastructure/datasource/client/ClientMapper.xml`.

Comment: @ave Thanks for your reply. I do actually have a ClientMapper.xml on that path. I just forgot to commit into my repository. Check again my project, it should be there by now.

Comment: @Leo `ClientMapper.xml` currently is in `src/main/java`. As I wrote, it should be in `src/main/resources`. Please check the path in my previous comment again. Also see this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36512321/1261766) for 'why'.

Comment: @ave I moved ClientMapper.xml to src/main/resources but still getting the same error. I also modified my build.gradle as well but still getting the same problem. I updated the project on my github so you can see what I did.

Comment: @RomanKonoval Sorry for not replying. Here is my project in my github https://github.com/nnakamura95/nutri/tree/develop

Comment: The current path is `nutri/nutri-api/src/main/resources/ClientMapper.xml`. The correct path is `nutri/nutri-api/src/main/resources/nutri/api/infrastructure/datasource/client/ClientMapper.xml`. Please compare it carefully.  BTW, there seems to be several other issues (property name mismatch, missing type handler for UUID).

Comment: @ave I was able to fix my problem. The reason why mybits wasn't recognizing mapper xml it's because I was missing these: `mybatis.type-aliases-package=nutri.api` and 
`mybatis.mapper-locations=classpath*:/mybatis/*Mapper.xml` on application.properties. Also, you were right about propert name mismatch and missing type handler for UUID. I fixed all of them and now my application is running! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For using mapper's declaration in xml file you should declare config file in the classpath (/src/main/resources)which will contain your mapper's declaration, for example `mybatis-config.xml`

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE configuration
            PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
            "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
    
    <configuration>
        <settings>
<!--        <setting name="aggressiveLazyLoading" value="false"/>-->
<!--        <setting name="lazyLoadingEnabled" value="false"/>-->
<!--        <setting name="mapUnderscoreToCamelCase" value="true"/>-->
<!--        <setting name="logImpl" value="SLF4J"/>-->
<!--        <setting name="jdbcTypeForNull" value="NULL"/>-->
<!--        <setting name="callSettersOnNulls" value="true"/>-->
        </settings>
        <typeAliases>
            <!-- Data Transfer Objects -->
        </typeAliases>
    
        <typeHandlers>
    <!--        <typeHandler handler="org.apache.ibatis.type.LocalDateTimeTypeHandler"/>-->
        </typeHandlers>
    
        <!-- explicit inclusion of reusable elements -->
        <mappers>
            <mapper resource="yourMapper.xml" />
        </mappers>
    </configuration>
```

Besides, you should set path for the config file in your SqlSessionFactory bean, for example:

```
@Bean
public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory(final DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
    SqlSessionFactoryBean bean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
    bean.setConfigLocation(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResource("classpath:mybatis-config.xml"));   
    bean.setDataSource(dataSource);

    return bean.getObject();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and a senior developer helped me figure out, that the Clientmapper.xml file should be in a similar package as the ClientMapper java interface.

Sometimes, when we create a directory in `src/main/resources` as `nutri.api.infrastructure.datasource.client`, it creates one folder with folder name `"nutri.api.infrastructure.datasource.client"`.

A way to go around would be to manually create this folder structure using System Explorer and just to be sure, you can also check the Project `Structure>Modules` and confirm that it has a hierarchical folder structure.